# How can I keep distinct scroll states for multiple scrolling items in a HorizontalPager within a (Lazy)Column with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to achieve the following layout:

[image: Layout]

The Non-Sticky Header should scroll out the screen, while the TabBar should be sticky. This is doable relatively easily using a `LazyColumn`, `stickyHeader()` and `item()`.

```
LazyColumn {
    item {
        NonStickyHeader()
    }

    stickyHeader {
        TabBar()
    }

    item {
        HorizontalPager(pageCount = items.size, state = rememberPagerState()) { idx ->
            Column {
                PageContent(idx)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this causes all pages to share the `ScrollState` of the `LazyColumn`, meaning that when scrolling on page 0 and then switching to page 1 the new page will also be scrolled to the position that was scrolled to on page 1. I would like each page to hold its own `ScrollState` and the headers to scroll in a nested way, i.e. the children only scroll if the parent header is maximally scrolled out.

I have tried the following:

- `Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())` on the pages

  - With `LazyColumn` this causes a crash since a list cannot be inside another list in Compose
  - Using Column and animating its offset based on a nestedScrollConnection - this did not result in smooth behavior and the page content was not displayed correctly

Are there any other, better ideas towards solving such an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now found a solution which works well enough for me. The basic setup is as follows:

- all content is in a non-scrolling `Column` with a `NestedScrollConnection`
- the header is contained in a `Box` whose size is varied based on (nested) scrolling
- the list content is only scrolled once the header has been fully collapsed, all other scroll events are "eaten" by the Column and propagated to the offset of the `Box`
- we hold a `ScrollState` for each child of the `HorizontalPager`

Code:

```
val itemScrollStates = (1..items.size).map { rememberScrollState() }

Column(Modifier.nestedScroll(object : NestedScrollConnection {
    override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
        return Offset(y = applyScrollDelta(available.y), x = 0f)
    }
})) {
    NonStickyTabHeader(headerHeight, headerScrollPos, header)

    TabBar()

    ContentPager(..., itemScrollStates)
}
```

Here `applyScrollDelta`calculates how much of the scroll delta should be used up for header:

```
fun applyScrollDelta(delta: Float): Float {
    val newScrollPos = headerScrollPos + delta
    val oldScrollPos = headerScrollPos

    val pageIdx = pagerState.currentPage
    val scrollState = itemScrollStates[pageIdx]
    
    // do not scroll if current child cannot scroll and header is fully visible
    if (!scrollState.canScrollForward && !scrollState.canScrollBackward && headerScrollPos == 0f) {
        return 0f
    }

    // only scroll backwards once current child is finished scrolling backwards
    if (scrollState.canScrollBackward && delta > 0) {
        val available = scrollState.value
        val diff = delta - available
        if (diff > 0) {
            headerScrollPos += diff
            return diff
        }
        return 0f
    }
    
    return if (newScrollPos > 0) {
        // max scroll of header should be 0, meaning it is fully visible
        headerScrollPos = 0f
        0f
    } else if (newScrollPos > -headerHeightPx) {
        // if possible consume all delta
        headerScrollPos = newScrollPos
        delta
    } else {
        // if reaching the end do not fully consume delta, only as much as needed
        headerScrollPos = -headerHeightPx
        headerHeightPx + oldScrollPos
    }
}
```

Finally the Header-Box is constructed as follows based on `headerHeight` and `headerScrollPos`:

```
@Composable
private fun NonStickyTabHeader(
    headerHeight: Dp,
    offsetY: Float,
    header: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .height(headerHeight + offsetY.pxToDp())
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .height(headerHeight)
                .offset { IntOffset(y = offsetY.roundToInt(), x = 0) }
        ) {
            header()
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `.verticalScroll`-Modifier on the outer Box, each direct child of the outer-most `Column` needs this modifier such that nested scroll events are properly captured.